# copyfile excel vba path error

Tags: excel, vba

what is wrong here:

defenition:

```
            Dim fso As Object, f As Object, ff As Object, f1 As Object
            Dim new_des As Object
            Application.ScreenUpdating = False
            Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
            Set f = fso.Getfolder("C:\test\new")
            Set ff = f.Files

            For Each f1 In ff......

            ....Set new_des = fso.Getfolder("C:\test\new\old" & "\" & f1).....

            ......FileCopy f1, new_des....
```

i have run time error 75 path not find to 'Set new_des.....'
the path is there
"f1" is holding the file

Answer (score 0):

`ff` is a `Files` collection, each `f1` in that is a file so

```
 fso.Getfolder("C:\test\new\old" & "\" & f1)
```

attemts to `GetFolder` on a file path which is not valid as it expect a directory path.

You need to path full path strings to `FileCopy`.

Answer (score 0):

i declare new_des as string and:
new_des = ("C:\test\new\old")
then i did:
FileCopy (f & f1), (new_des & f1)

Answer (score 0):

to copy all files use:

```
fso.CopyFolder "C:\test\new", "C:\test\new\old" 'from new to old
```

or if you want to do in your code, use `BuildPath()` to concatenate the folder with the file, `GetFileName()` to get file name of `f1` and define `new_des as String` to save the generated path:

```
dim new_des as String
new_des = fso.BuildPath("C:\test\new\old\", fso.GetFileName(f1))
```